# Enabling R8 crashes application

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, obfuscation, android-r8

So I enabled R8 in my project by adding `android.enableR8=true` to gradle.properties.
This is my gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard false
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            multiDexEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
...
```

But when I run a build, I got this crash when app launches:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.application.MyApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1069)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at com.example.application.MyApplication.<init>(MyApplication.kt:18)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1120)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I added those on my proguard file, so R8 don't remove or obfuscate anything

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
```

and the app still crashes.

I tried to migrate to Proguard by setting `android.enableR8=false` to gradle.properties and `useProguard true` in Gradle file, and the app worked fine without crashing.

Did anyone encounter the same issue?

Btw, my project is in Kotlin.

Comment: This is most likely due to a missing keep rule. If the application use reflection directly or indirectly keep rules are required to tell R8 about use which cannot be statically determined. The explicit `throw null` that you encounter could be due to use of a class which R8 has determined is never instantiated. In that case R8 will rewrite any access to members of instances of that class to `throw null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we have bundled android.jar in some modules, but it should only be on the bootclasspath, as the Android Team said in the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167913510) I created on IssueTracker.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you look at the output from R8 to see if there are any warnings that might point you in the right direction. If you can consistently reproduce the issue, you can file an issue with R8: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Matt. Already printed the usage and seeds (-printusage ../usage.txt and -printseeds ../seeds.txt) but unfortunately could not find the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with an application that was minified with `R8` and `ProGuard`. I simply removed the `ProGuard` minification from the `bulid.gradle`.